# How to pass the value from the one select to another select in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pass the `Id` from this SELECT (Master):

`SELECT x.id, ............ FROM xx INNER JOIN xx ON xx = xx ........`  (eg: 100 rows)

to (Child)

`SELECT a,b from xxxxx..... where id in (x.id)`   (eg: also 100 rows)

finally combine both the output together

What's in my mind :

```
select z.id,...........,z.a,z.b
(
  SELECT x.id, ............ FROM xx INNER JOIN xx ON xx = xx ........  (eg:         100 rows)

  SELECT a,b from xxxxx..... where id in (x.id)   (eg: also 100 rows)
) z
```

My problem is how to pass the id into the other select.

Found a solution but the rows of child is not match with master as the key(id) in the master does not exist in child table:

```
SELECT z.id, sum(a), sum(b), z.xx, z.xx from xxxxx.....,(SELECT x.id, ............ FROM xx INNER JOIN xx     ON xx = xx ........) as z where id in (z.id) group by z.id
```

How can i output the result like when it detects the id is not exists in the child the Sum(a) and sum(b) will be displayed like (-).

PS: Each select query is joining multiple table.

Sample Table (200 rows):

Id,m,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5

1,...

2,...

3,...

4,...

5,...

6,...

Child :

Id,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5

1,...

1,...

1,...

5,...

5,...

6,...

Expected Output:

(pass all the id in master to child)

Result (should also 200 rows):

Id,m1,m2,m3,SUM(c1),SUM(c2)

1,...

2,m1,m2,m3,-,-

3,m1,m2,m3,-,-

4,m1,m2,m3,-,-

5,...

6,...

Solved (Brain Malfunction, my bad):

```
SELECT x.id, ............,AwaitingA, AwaitingB FROM xx INNER JOIN xx     ON xx = xx ........
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id, sum(a) as AwaitingA, sum(b) as AwaitingB from xxxxx..... group by ....) d
on x.id = d.id
```

Comment: Can't you just use `LEFT JOIN`?

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
   SELECT a,b from xxxxx..... where id in ( SELECT x.id FROM xx INNER JOIN xx ON xx = xx)
```

Comment: How about the other columns? select it again? This query just giving me a and b, I need the other columns too which are in the subquery as you provided.

Comment: @Tom can you please share your sample table with daata and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a sub-query.

Looks something like this:

```
select * from a where a.id in (select id from b);
```

Edit:  If you want multiple columns from a to filter on you will have to do multiple sub-queries.

```
select * from a where a.id in (select id from b) and a.xx in (select xx from c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.id into #IDTempTable where etc.
```

then

```
SELECT a,b from xxx inner join #IDTempTable as tt on tt.id = xxx.id
```

Can you use a temporary table in your solution? Whether you get the same number of rows of course depends on the IDs being unique.